# Create more upselling modules per product

Tags: magento2, upselling

I want to define several upsell modules instead of just one. How can I add additional upsell categories (i.e. Accessoirs for example)?

Basically I want to do something based on this module: 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-accessories.html

How would I do that in **Magento 2**?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both related and upsell for the same kind of use, but that still would limit you to max 2 categories. Another solution would be a custom made feature where you either connect complete hiden or un-hiden categories to products. This would be a great fit if many products share the same accessories.

If those both kinda easy solution wont fit your needs, you are looking to a special made extension which i did not find just yet.

Comment: Can't i just duplicate the existing upsell products module and modify it to my needs?

Comment: in short your should be able to but a lot more changes need to happen to get that working like you want to. Since the product needs to know which upsell belongs to what upsell module so that would take some custom coding